# Flutter: How should I go about adding gujarati support?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, localization, hindi

I am building an app for a grocery store, their main customers are Gujarati speaking, so they want their app in Gujarati too, so how should I go about doing that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the internationalization documentation here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Comment: Yes, I tried, but using that method one won't be able to choose in which language to use the app in. As most people don't use their phone with default language being Gujarati.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, and several plugins to do internationalization if Flutter apps. Just say `flutter i18n` to Google, and you will get a pletoria of results.

But personally, I use for my apps a Visual Studio Code extension to manage translations. The extension name is [vscode-flutter-i18n-json](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esskar.vscode-flutter-i18n-json). It's very easy to use and to maintain, and the integration with the editor it's a plus.

Just install, follow instructions on the readme, and you will get your translations ready for your app. The extension is also capable to auto translate your text if you have a Google Translate API key).

*Since there is no unique and dedicated way to get translations on a Flutter app, I've just shared my own :-)*

Hope this will help!